# Retrieve Text from multiple spans with the same class name

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

My friend made his own random number generator on his website and challenged me to find a way to make some sort of script that could automatically answer the random number generator. I'm an engineer, not a programmer, so I don't really know anything about this and I would like to learn.
So far what I have seen is that the random number generator puts 4 different spans into a division so they all appear in their own boxes. They all have the same class name and I would somehow like to make a script that automaically retrieves the information from the spans and inputs it into a text box.

```
<div id="numgen">
 <div class="numgen-content">
    <span class="numgen-number">3</span>
    <span class="numgen-number">7</span>
    <span class="numgen-number">1</span>
    <span class="numgen-number">9</span>
    <input name="numgen-input" type="text" id="numgen-input">
 </div>
</div>
```

After searching around on the internet and learning a bit about jquery I found this small script that I could use

```
$("span[class='numgen-number']");
```

however, when I used it, it returned

```
<span class=​"numgen-number">​3​</span>​
```

Having little knowledge of this, I would like some assistance.

Answer (score 1):

No jQuery or library required:

```
var textArray = Array.prototype.slice.call(document.querySelectorAll('.numgen-number')).map(function(span){
    return span.textContent;
});
```

Answer (score 0):

something like this should do the trick:

```
function getNumbers() {
    $output = $("#numgen-input");
    $(".numgen-number").each(function(index, item) {
        $output.val($output.val() + $(item).text());
    });
}
```

then add a button or something to call getNumbers()

Demo: http://jsfiddle.net/Ag7La/2/

Comment: Is there a certain way I have to run this? Because so far, I have simply been using the chrome console and everything has been working, but when I tried this, it gave me "TypeError: undefined is not a function"

Comment: Yes, the fiddle working, but when I try this on the website it simply gives me that error

Comment: Make sure you have jquery added in the header, and that you are calling getNumbers() function after the HTML has loaded, either through the console, or a button press or something!

Comment: Sorry for causing you trouble, but it is now giving me an error "ReferenceError: $ is not defined" I'm running this off of the chrome console, if that has something to do with it.

Comment: `$ is not defined` means that either jQuery is not included, or the script is running before jQuery is included.